# Movie about a man who can see personalities

Tags: story-identification, movie, psychic

I remember watching a movie on TV about a man who could "see" the "voices" in people's minds. These voices were depicted as people. I'm not sure if everyone had these voices. Maybe he could only see these voices with people with issues, but I'm not sure. This was at least 10 years ago.

In the story, a policeman asks this man to help him on a case/cases. I remember two of them interrogating a single person, and the seeing multiple personalities being interrogated. So there were like 10+ people in the room, but in reality there were only three.

He could see people with 2-3 personalities/voices, and this seemed normal to him. There was one guy with around 10 and I think he was the suspect that was being interrogated.

I feel like it was an Asian movie.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for Movies and Tv?

Comment: Movies & TV don't do ID questions...so **NO**!

Comment: @Paulie_D - Plus they were pretty poor at answering them anyway

Comment: We answered what we could...but objected to the quality *overall*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the movie you're thinking of is *[Mad Detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Detective)* (神探) from 2007:

> Chan Kwai-Bun (Sean Lau) is a brilliant detective with a supernatural
>   gift: seeing a person's "inner personalities" or hidden ghosts.

I saw this a few years ago and remember it being really visually interesting (also, just a good movie overall). It’s from Hong Kong.

<sub>**Warning: Trailer is NSFW (gory)**</sub>

Comment: Yep, this is it. The bandage on his head was another thing that I remembered :)